# Sort multi dimensional array by 3 values, or split array into 3 arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multi dimensional array like this:

```
maildate | mag | panel | status
2-22-16 | green | 1 | pending
2-22-16 | green | 3 | completed
2-22-16 | green | 2 | working
2-23-16 | red | 1 | pending
2-22-16 | blue | 1 | complete
```

I need to sort by the status first, then date, then the mag and then the version. I have tried to use this function and it works good for the status, but I cannot get it to then do the date within the same status.

```
// function to sort mulitdimensional array by key
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();
    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
            $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    switch ($order) {
        case SORT_ASC:
            asort($sortable_array);
            break;
        case SORT_DESC:
            arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
    }
    foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
    }
}
return $new_array;
}
// sort lblist array by status
$lblist = array_sort($lblist, 'status', SORT_ASC);
```

I also have this function, which seems to work, but the status groups get divided up.

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b){
if ($b['status'] == $a['status']) {
if ($b['maildate'] == $a['maildate']) {
    if ($b['mag'] == $a['mag']) {
        return $b['panel'] - $a['panel'];
        }
    else {
        return $b['mag'] - $a['mag'];
        }
    }
else {
    return $b['maildate'] - $a['maildate'];
    }
}
else {
return $b['status'] - $a['status'];
}
}
usort($lblist, 'sortByOrder');
```

I thought maybe to divide the array by the status once it is sort by that to keep them together and then do the other sorts on each "sub" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) but first capturing the inner arrays:

```
// RECREATE ARRAY    
$mail = array();
$mail[0]['maildate'] = '2-22-16'; $mail[0]['mag'] = 'green'; $mail[0]['panel'] = 1; $mail[0]['status'] = 'pending';
$mail[1]['maildate'] = '2-22-16'; $mail[1]['mag'] = 'green'; $mail[1]['panel'] = 3; $mail[1]['status'] = 'completed';
$mail[2]['maildate'] = '2-22-16'; $mail[2]['mag'] = 'green'; $mail[2]['panel'] = 2; $mail[2]['status'] = 'working';
$mail[3]['maildate'] = '2-23-16'; $mail[3]['mag'] = 'red';   $mail[3]['panel'] = 1; $mail[3]['status'] = 'pending';
$mail[4]['maildate'] = '2-22-16'; $mail[4]['mag'] = 'blue';  $mail[4]['panel'] = 1; $mail[4]['status'] = 'completed';

$maildate = array();
$mag = array();
$panel = array();
$status = array();

// CAPTURE INNER ARRAYS
foreach ($mail as $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'maildate': $maildate[] = date_create_from_format('m-d-y', $value)->format('Y-m-d'); break;
            case 'mag': $mag[] = $value; break;
            case 'panel': $panel[] = $value; break;
            case 'status': $status[] = $value; break;
        }
    }
}

// APPLY MULTIPLE SORTS TO MAIN ARRAY
array_multisort($status, SORT_ASC, $maildate, SORT_ASC, 
                $mag, SORT_ASC, $panel, SORT_ASC, $mail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking back at the array in the question (though it's text and not actual code) you probably want to normalize it.  Try this before the sort:

```
foreach($lblist as $row) {
    $array[] = array_combine($lblist[0], $row);
}
```

So you can extract each of the columns and sort on those in order and sort the original array based on that order.  Notice that the `maildate` needs to be converted to a timestamp to sort correctly and `mm-dd-YY` is not valid with dashes `-`.  Dashes use `dd-mm-YY` so you need `/` for `mm/dd/YY`. Change to `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC` wherever needed:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'status'), SORT_ASC,
                array_map('strtotime',
                    str_replace('-', '/',
                        array_column($array, 'maildate'))), SORT_ASC,
                array_column($array, 'mag'), SORT_ASC,
                array_column($array, 'panel'), SORT_ASC,
                $array);
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).  Or check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php and use the `foreach()` approach to create arrays to use in the sort.

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    $status[] = $row['status'];
    $date[]   = $row['maildate'];
    $mag[]    = $row['mag'];
    $panel[]  = $row['panel'];
}
```

Then replace the `array_column()` calls in the sort with the arrays ceated above.

**Note**:  On the off chance this is coming from a database, just:

```
SELECT maildate, mag, panel, status FROM table_name ORDER BY status, maildate, mag, panel
```

Using a database function to convert `maildate` into a sortable format such as `YYYY-mm-dd` (example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: It is coming from a data base, but all of the elements of the array are not in the same row in the database.  The status changes with each row for a given item.  Only the first row has the maildate, mag, and panel.  I have to do a second query to get the latest status.  But that was another problem.  Thanks

Comment: OK, you might ask a separate question with your database table structures and you may get a good way to query it already sorted.

Comment: The mail date is a time stamp so I used this:`code`array_multisort(
 array_column($lblist, 'status'), SORT_ASC,
 array_column($lblist, 'maildate'), SORT_ASC,
 array_column($lblist, 'mag'), SORT_ASC,
 array_column($lblist, 'panel'), SORT_ASC,
 $lblist
 );
 but it gives me nothing, actually stops the page from loading all the way.

Comment: Looks like I do not have array_column defined (does not exist).